# How can I stop my <table> overlapping the rounded corners of its parent <div>?

Tags: css, border

I have a `<table>` with alternate colored rows in a `<div>` with rounded corners. When I scroll vertically , the table overlaps the rounded edges and the edges are not seen rounded.

Is there any solution to maintain the rounded corner?

Comment: eww tables. Post some css/html/jsfiddle link?

Comment: Have you tried adding margin or padding to the table?

Comment: @Calum - give him a chance, he might be displaying tabular data

Comment: i have alternate colored rows, so padding and margin is not looking good

Answer (score 1):

Give your div a padding value equal to the radius of your rounded corner.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the z-index of your table to be -1 or some other value so that the table corners are below your div when you scroll up. But if you don't want the corners of your table to appear rounded when you scroll up, then padding is your best option.

Comment: table is inside a scrollable div. So i can put z-index:-1 to the div, then scroll and table row click will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow: hidden;` in the css definition.